# To find an intersection point between two planes with only the direction vector

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

Find the intersection between two planes $x−3y−2z = 2$ and $2x+y+3z = 1$

Solution:

$(1)$$\quad n_1 \times n_2 =\langle −7,7,7\rangle =7 \langle −1,1,1\rangle$.

$(2)$ To find one intersection point, we let $z = 0$. Then $x = \frac{5}{7},y = - \frac{3}{7}$.

where did they get:

$z = 0$

$x = \frac{5}{7}$

$y = - \frac{3}{7}$

For the point on the line?

Comment: The intersection is a line. You have got a point of this line and its direction. So you have completely determined it.

Comment: Yes but how was the point determined?  Where did they get P(5/7,3/7,0) from?

Comment: You have to look for any point which belongs to both planes. That is, you have to find a solution of the system. Since it has two equations and three variables they fixed $z=0$ and look for a solution of $x-3y=2,2x+y=1,$ which gives you the point.

Comment: Thank you ugh I feel so dumb.

Comment: When you set z = 0, you're assuming the 3D line where the planes intersect cannot be parallel to the x-y plane.  That seriously detracts from the generality of the approach.

Answer (score 1):

Finding a point in common requires us to solve the system
\begin{align*}
x−3y−2z &= 2\\
2x+y+3z &= 1
\end{align*}
Depending on your level of sophistication, we can either use linear algebra to solve this system, or maybe multiply the first equation by $-2$ and add them, etc...